# I want to set up discourse,but i meet this error.when i run 'bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0' in window powershell,it show me this

Tags: ruby, vagrant

```
root@base-debootstrap:/vagrant# bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:190:in `rename': Text file busy @ rb_file_s_rename - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.48546387545184877.3435, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:190:in `clobber_pid'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:220:in `pid='
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /vagrant/bin/unicorn:48:in `load'
        from /vagrant/bin/unicorn:48:in `<main>'
```

If you can help me, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have the file open (say in a text editor or IDE) on the host that your VM is on?

Comment: no,i just run command in window powershell

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands, this may help you

```
  ps aux | grep 3000
```

You will get process pid then run

```
  kill -9 pid
```

or you can directly go to tmp->pids->server.pid in your project and delete the server.pid file.
then try to start your server again it will work